# Length condition different than 0 being ignored

Tags: jquery

I have the following condition:

```
 if ($('div.table-wrap tr td.foo-row').length != 0) { 

// do soemthing
}
```

It works when my table looks like this:

```
      <tr>
        <td class="foo-row"></td>
        <td class="foo-row">></td>
        <td class="foo-row"></td>
        <td class="foo-row"></td>
      </tr>
```

But it doesn't when it looks like this:

```
      <tr>
        <td class="foo-row"></td>
        <td class="foo-row2"></td>
        <td class="foo-row2"></td>
        <td class="foo-row3"></td>
        <td class="foo-row2"></td>
      </tr>
```

My purpose is that the condition will work even if at least one TD has the class `foo-row`, which happens in both cases, so why it doesn't work in the first case?

Comment: Have you checked what exactly `$('div.table-wrap tr td.foo-row')` returns?

Comment: No reason it shouldn't work....assuming the rows exist when you run that code. Provide a [mcve]

Comment: I don't know how, someone made this code for me:)

Comment: Show us how and where you use it in a more complete example that doesn't work

Comment: Oh I'm such a goonie, the other table has different class, not `table-wrap`.
So can I go by  `if ($('table tr td.foo-row').length != 0) { ` ?

Answer (score 0):

This is the exact match `$('div.table-wrap tr td.foo-row')` for the cell with the class `foo-row`.

How about using wildcard selector for any `.foo-row*`.

Example:

```
if ($('div.table-wrap tr td[class*="foo-row"]').length != 0) { 
     // do soemthing
}
```

You could make it more specific for the classes not containing but starting with `foo-row` by replacing `td[class*="foo-row"]` to `td[class^="foo-row"]`.

Comment: @charlietfl It's hard to explain exactly for not exact question.

Comment: well I don't see how providing a solution to do something different helps